# Allow me to disable preview while answering in MathJax enabled sites

Tags: feature-request, markdown-preview, mathjax

I was recently posting a fairly extensive answer on chemistry, that contained a lot of MathJax expressions. While typing it, my browser (Chrome) kept reinterpreting these commands, which significantly slowed down everything. I was looking for the hide preview button, but could not find it.
When I just edit a question, I am able to hide the preview. Why is there a difference between editing and answering?

While I know it is important, especially for new users, to have to scroll past the preview, and be able/forced to review the post this way, I think I do now know what I am doing most of the time and I would like to be able to toggle the preview.
Is there a way to temporarily disable the MathJax rendering?
Is there a way to disable the preview while answering (at least for more experienced users)?

I am posting this here and not in meta.chemistry, because this might be present on any other sites where Mathjax is enabled. Here is a screenshot to illustrate what I mean.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Title changed to reflect actual feature request.

Comment: Related to this, there is an experimental fast renderer for MathJax (the fast HTML option in the context menu). This should speed up MathJax significantly, but it doesn't support enough of the features of the main renderer yet.

Comment: @MadScientist Thanks for pointing out that option, that will definitely work as a temporary solution while writing extensive answers.

Comment: @Martin At the moment you're very likely to run into issues with it, there are a lot of features not supported yet.

Comment: Duplicate acros meta: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19773/only-view-mathjax-in-preview-on-button-press which has a solution (bookmarklets).